# Is it possible to add bar points with text for chart js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

I would like to add scale labels at the top of each bar in my chart.
I have no excisting code for it or a clue on how too. Would appriciate a starting point.

Comment: Did you check with highchart.js library

Comment: @shreya No but thanks for the tip. At the moment I don't have the time to replace chartjs.

Answer (score 1):

**this will surely help you out its quite simple and free for learning and very interactive**

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/>
```

Answer (score 1):

this will help you then

**example:**

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/xqdv1gzw/3/>
```

and

**documentation** is:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration